# how to pull from previous test case in cypress

Tags: cypress

I am currently studying cypress and as I was going through the tutorials one thing popped up in my mind. What if I wrote a small test case to, for example, open a website, click login and enter the credentials. Then I want to start a new test case to do something else on that website once logged in but on a different test case. Can I pull the information from the first one?

What I mean is this:

```
describe('My first test', function () {
it('login as user', function () {
   
    cy.visit('https://uat2.myregus.com/home')

    cy
        .get('#header_LogIn').click()
        .get('#Username').click()
        .type('dogejaq@getairmail.com')
        .type('{enter}')
        .get('.password').click()
        .type('Test_123!')
        .type('{enter}')
})
```

})

Then my second case would pull the information from the above so that I can continue.

```
describe('My second test', function () {
it('book a meeting', function () {
   
    cy.visit('https://uat2.myregus.com/home')
  
})
```

})

The reason I want to do this is because I don't want to run both tests every time. Essentially it would log me in every time using those credentials. I was thinking of making a separate .js file to pull from but I am not sure how. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Coupling multiple tests together is an anti-pattern. Your tests should always be able to be run independently from one another and still pass.

See docs from Cypress best practices [here](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Having-tests-rely-on-the-state-of-previous-tests).

The code from your first test should be wrapped in a `beforeEach` hook so it can be run before each `it()`:

```js
describe('My second test', function () {
    beforeEach(() => {
        cy
            .get('#header_LogIn').click()
            .get('#Username').click()
            .type('dogejaq@getairmail.com')
            .type('{enter}')
            .get('.password').click()
            .type('Test_123!')
            .type('{enter}')
    })

    it('book a meeting', function () {
   
        cy.visit('https://uat2.myregus.com/home')
  
    })

    it('does something else', function () {
        cy.visit('...')
    })
})
```

You should also have a look at these [logging in recipes](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes#logging-in-recipes) to perform backend authentication instead of going through the UI to log in before each test.

Comment: It seems silly to me that https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices#Having-Tests-Rely-On-The-State-Of-Previous-Tests calls it an anti-pattern but then recommends "Combine multiple tests into one larger test." That seems like just moving the problem around. But that's the approach I took.

Comment: You're right, but what they try to explain is that it's better to have 1 big independent test than multiple smaller tests that depend on each other.
Personally, I would go with the 2nd option and use a beforeEach hook

Comment: Yeah but that option greatly increases how long it takes the tests to run, which I want to avoid. +1 for the link.